# functional testing carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, functional-testing

I'm using carrierwave in rails 4 to upload images. I'm having a few issues with functional tests, specifically "image_url" used in the view.

I'm using namespace routing and related models.

I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/lperry65/f72260a17f29fae18544

here is the error I'm getting when I run the following product test:

```
test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:products)
end

1) Error:
Admin::ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/admin/products/index.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_admin_products_index_html_erb__290306839054085465_2161027740'
    app/views/admin/products/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_admin_products_index_html_erb__290306839054085465_2161027740'
    test/controllers/admin/products_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

This is because of this line in the view:

```
<td><%= image_tag product.images[0].image_url(:thumb).to_s %></td>
```

This is the first time I've used carrierwave so any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm also looking for some help with a similar problem.